# Semantic-ui menu not working as intended

Tags: html, semantic-ui

```
<div class="ui pointing menu">
        <a class="item" data-tab="first">FIRST</a>
        <a class="item active" data-tab="second">SECOND</a>
</div>
```

I have a menu setup like this and the script is:

```
$('.menu .item').on('click', function() {
$('.menu .item').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

There are no errors or anything but the menu just doesn't work. I also tried with

```
$('.menu .item').tab();
```

script as shown in semantic's examples.

What can I do to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: is this all the code for the UI? is the menu rendered to screen after as it seems an issue that the listener is applied before the menu exists

Comment: @Quince I just moved the script tag to the bottom of the html file (don't know if that is good practice) and it solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: To ensure the page is ready for your scripts to run you can wrap your code in a `document-ready` function http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/